# Django cms - Javascript "undefined" string alert error when trying to publish or unpublish page on page list

Tags: python, django, web, django-cms

My project is a brand new installation of django-cms 2.4.1 running with MySQL.

When I try to publish or unpublish a page through page list interface, it pops up a Javascript alert error with the string "undefined". The weird thing is that it does the action (publish or unpublish) despite of the error. It won't enable the check box when I try to publish, but after I reload the page it shows published and checked. If I try to unpublish it disables the checkbox.

Just to emphasize that if I try to perform this actions through the editing form it works perfectly.

I don't seem to find any problem in my settings.py that might be causing it.

I inspected the ajax request trhough Chrome inspector and everything seems to be OK!

The response is just fine as follows:

```
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/cms/page/11/change-status/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK!
```

[Preview tab from Chrome inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPlJO.png)

Please guys, give me a hand on it.

This is my settings.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
gettext = lambda s: s
from datetime import datetime
from run_locale import local_run

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
PROJECT_NAME='zecaffe'

PRODUCTION = False
TESTE_SERVER = False
DEBUG = True
print "Running at: "+local_run
if local_run == 'producao':
    PRODUCTION = True
    DEBUG = False
elif local_run == 'teste':
    TESTE_SERVER = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

if PRODUCTION and TESTE_SERVER:
    raise Exception(u"""
        Django: Conflito de configuração. Apenas uma entre as variáveis PRODUCTION e TESTE_SERVER
        pode ser definida como True.
        """
    )

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@domain.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

if PRODUCTION:
    PAGE_TO_EMAIL = 'email@example.com.br'
elif TESTE_SERVER:
    PAGE_TO_EMAIL = 'email@example.com.br'
else:
    PAGE_TO_EMAIL = 'email@example.com.br'


CMS_SEO_FIELDS = True
CMS_REDIRECTS = True

if PRODUCTION:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE' : 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME' : '[database-name]',
            'USER' : '[database-user]',
            'PASSWORD' : '[databse-pass]',
            'HOST' : 'localhost',
            'PORT' : '',
        }
    }

elif TESTE_SERVER:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE' : 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME' : '[database-name]',
            'USER' : '[database-user]',
            'PASSWORD' : '[databse-pass]',
            'HOST' : 'localhost',
            'PORT' : '',
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE' : 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME' : '[database-name]',
            'USER' : '[database-user]',
            'PASSWORD' : '[databse-pass]',
            'HOST' : 'localhost',
            'PORT' : '',
        }
    }


TIME_ZONE = 'America/Sao_Paulo'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-br'

LANGUAGES = (
    ('pt-br', gettext(u'Português Brasil')),
)

"""
CMS_LANGUAGES = {
    1: [
        {
            'code': 'pt-br',
            'name': gettext(u'Português Brasil'),
            #'fallbacks': ['de', 'fr'],
            'public': True,
            'hide_untranslated': False,
            'redirect_on_fallback':False,
        },
    ],

    'default': {
        'fallbacks': ['pt-br'],
        'redirect_on_fallback':True,
        'public': False,
        'hide_untranslated': False,
    }
}
"""

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

if PRODUCTION:
    # Caminho absoluto dentro do servidor
    MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/[user]/webapps/zecaffe/zecaffe/media/'
    STATIC_ROOT = '/home/[user]/webapps/zecaffe/zecaffe/static/'

elif TESTE_SERVER:
    MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/[user]/webapps/teste_zecaffe/zecaffe/media/'
    STATIC_ROOT = '/home/[user]/webapps/teste_zecaffe/zecaffe/static/'

else:
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'media')
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('admin', os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'admin')),
    ('cms', os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'cms')),
    ('ckeditor', os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'ckeditor')),
    ('css', os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'css')),
    ('img', os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'img')),
    ('js', os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'js')),
    ('jquery_ui', os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'jquery_ui')),
    ('galleria', os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'galleria')),
    #('font-face', os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'font-face')),
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '-----------------------------------'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
    'zecaffe.middlewares.ThreadLocals'
    #'django_globals.middleware.Global',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.tz',
    'cms.context_processors.media',
    'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',

    'core.context_processors.crop_settings',
    'core.context_processors.paginas',
    'core.context_processors.revisao',
    'core.context_processors.site_domain',
    'core.context_processors.facebook_settings',
    'core.context_processors.twitter_settings',
)

CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ('index.html', u'Template | Início'),
    #('colunas_inicio.html', u'Template | Colunas Início'),
    #('colunas_colunista.html', u'Template | Colunas Colunista'),
    ('contato.html', u'Template | Contato'),
)

ROOT_URLCONF = '%s.urls' % PROJECT_NAME

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates'),
)

#----------------------------CKEDITOR SETTINGS--------------------------------#
CKEDITOR_MEDIA_PREFIX  = "/media/ckeditor/"

if PRODUCTION:
    CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH =  '/home/[user]/webapps/zecaffe/zecaffe/media/ckeditor_imgs/'
elif TESTE_SERVER:
    CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH =  '/home/[user]/webapps/teste_zecaffe/zecaffe/media/ckeditor_imgs/'
else:
    CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH =  os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'media/ckeditor_imgs/')

#CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PREFIX = "http://localhost:8000/media/ckeditor_imgs/"

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'Full',
        'height': 300,
        'width': 1200,
        #'skin' : 'v2',
    },
}
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#

# ------------------ MYOWN SETTINGS ------------------#
DEBUG_EXCEPTIONS = True
if PRODUCTION:
    REVISAO = '55a88aa'
else:
    REVISAO = time = int(datetime.now().microsecond)

if PRODUCTION:
    SITE_DOMAIN = 'http://zecaffe.com.br/'
elif TESTE_SERVER:
    SITE_DOMAIN = 'http://teste.zecaffe.com.br/'
else:
    SITE_DOMAIN = 'http://localhost:8000/'

if PRODUCTION or TESTE_SERVER:
    FACEBOOK_APP_ID = '-----'
    FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET = '------'

    TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = '------'
    TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = '------'

else:
    FACEBOOK_APP_ID = ''
    FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET = ''

    TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = '------'
    TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = '-------'


CROP_SETTINGS = {
     'noticia':{
        'imagem_original' : (640, 480),
        'imagem_destaque_g_temp'  : (286, 156),
        'imagem_destaque_p_temp' : (200, 220),
        'imagem_destaque_w_temp' : (71, 71),
    },
     'galeria_imagem':{
        'imagem_light_box'  : (800, 600),
        'imagem_slide' : (700, 350),
        'thumb' : (125, 80),
    }

}
#----------------------------------------------------------#

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'cms',
    'menus',
    'mptt',
    'south',
    'sekizai',
    'cms.plugins.text',
    'cms.plugins.picture',
    'cms.plugins.link',
    'cms.plugins.file',
    'cms.plugins.flash',
    'cms.plugins.teaser',
    'cms.plugins.video',
    'cms.plugins.twitter',
    'cms.plugins.snippet',
    'cms.plugins.googlemap',
    'ckeditor',
    'core',
    'noticia',
    'social',
)

"""
CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF = {
    'content': {
        'plugins': ['TextPlugin', 'PicturePlugin'],
        'text_only_plugins': ['LinkPlugin'],
        'extra_context': {"width":640},
        'name':gettext("Content"),
    },
    'right-column': {
        "plugins": ['TeaserPlugin', 'LinkPlugin'],
        "extra_context": {"width":280},
        'name':gettext("Right Column"),
        'limits': {
            'global': 2,
            'TeaserPlugin': 1,
            'LinkPlugin': 1,
        },
    },
    'base.html content': {
        "plugins": ['TextPlugin', 'PicturePlugin', 'TeaserPlugin']
    },
}
"""

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.webfaction.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '[mailbox]'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '[mailbox-pass]'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'email@example.com.br'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'email@example.com.br'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = u'Zé Caffé'


LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Please guys, give me a hand on it.

This is my settings.py

Please guys, give me a hand on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happened to me once, are you migrating from an older version of django-cms? If yes, you should check your django admin templates, because there are some crazy conflicts over there if you're using the newer django-cms with older templates from previous versions. So make sure to  replace all of your older admin static files and templates from django/django-cms to the new ones. You can find it on your env /site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates, /site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin and /site-packages/cms/static folders.

If you're not migrating and it's a fresh installation, that's really odd.

Comment: You just saved the universe, many thanks. I was using the old templates indeed! Sorry for my dumbness. I thought I copied the templates from the right env directory, but I actually copied from an env from an older project.

Comment: Gustavo, I appear to be having template issues, too.  I would like to take your advise and make sure I am using the correct templates, how do I go about doing that?  Should django-cms be replacing some of the default admin templates/static files?  When I compared the two folder structures, they are the same.

Comment: Hi Sam. You should make sure to copy the admin static files from the path of your instalation package to you project path. Even the different versions of cms having the same structures, usually there are few changes on css and js that causes some bugs.

To properly copy the static files to your project you should run the collectstatic command.